# How do use the input of an HTML <select> tag as a value to get Django Models data, that has that particular input as one of it's data?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm using an HTML `<select>` tag to let the user select the title of a project, where the project is a QuerySet in a Django Model. So I want to use that value to display other data concerned with that project to the user.
The name of the HTML `<select>` is select_project. In my views.py, I use the `request.POST['select_project']`and store it in a variable `selected_project`. In order to get other data in the QuerySet, I used `Project.objects.filter(title=selected_project)` and stored it in a variable `displayed_project` which I then used in a View where the user sees all the information about that QuerySet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvbaC.png)

But when the user goes to the view, he gets nothing. Only an empty <QuerySet[]>. Please could you help suggest a way around this?

```
<select class="select_project" name="select_project">
    {%for project in projects%}
    <option value="" name='select_project'>{{project.title}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
```

Views.py

```
    def overview(request):
        if request.method=='POST':
            selected_project=request.POST['select_project']
            displayed_project=Project.objects.filter(title=selected_project)
            return render (request, 'core/overview.html', {
            'displayed_project':displayed_project
            })
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add an image for the displayed `html` output generated by Django for this select. Just right click on this element and select `inspect element`. I want to see if your select element is good

Comment: Alright, I'll add it to the post. From it, you can see "Building in Lagos" is the only project title listed as an option, as the Model currently has only 1 QuerySet. Anything you see off about it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to fill the value and name in  tag with the value of every project id or title. For example:

```html
<select class="select_project" name="select_project">
    {%for project in projects%}
    <option value="{{project.id}}" name='{{project.title}}'>{{project.title}}</option>
    {%endfor%}
```

If there will be a problem again, please write here

Comment: Thanks but I got a MultiValueDictKeyError on the page where the QuerySet data is supposed to be displayed. However, I had used request.POST['{{project.title}}'] due to your suggestion of that as the new name for the select tag.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue. So I did not know that my View gets the value of the `<select>` and not actually it's content. So I then added the `project.id` to the value of the `<select>` tag. With that done, and after getting the POST data, I filtered the QuerySet using the ID like so:
`Project.objects.filter(pk=selected_project)`
and at the end, I got the data in the Overview page.

Thanks!